# Job listings show money figures in ambiguous currency

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

For example, this job: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/98488/lead-software-engineer-ninja-van is in Singapore and says "$70,000 - 120,000." Is that US dollars or Singapore dollars?

This should be made abundantly clear on the site, not just for Singapore jobs but also for users who are in Singapore who may be viewing jobs in Australia (also "$"), Canada ("$"), etc.

Personally I prefer three-letter ISO currency codes like SGD, USD, JPY, etc, but there are other local conventions as well, such as "S$100" for Singapore and "US$100" if you prefer.

Comment: It'd be nice if there was a tooltip on the amount showing the amount of the local currency of the user viewing the post.

Comment: @XO: I'd be quite happy to just see the actual units of the salary presented clearly.  As a second step, sure, if you want to ask users to set a currency in their profile (and use their location to default that), that'd be swell too.  But I'd settle for simply knowing whether I'm being paid in AUD/CAD/USD/etc.

Answer (score 12):

Employers have the option of choosing any currency when entering a salary. In this particular case, it's SGD($). We'll look into adding more info to the listing (I THINK I read we're going to do this, not sure if/when which is why I'm going to mark it status-deferred.)

Comment: So you're saying that you ask the employer to specify a currency when entering the job (in this case SGD), but then you present the listing to the end user with an ambiguous symbol like `$`?  If so, please just present to the user with the ISO code.  Everyone can understand the one for their local market, at least.  When I see a single list of jobs with salaries in "$" I certainly have no expectation that the units could be all different.  Given the low barrier to fix this vs the high visibility I hope you will un-defer soon.  :)

Comment: @JohnZwinck I totally agree it's ambiguous. It's just at this moment we have our hands full with the Jobs tab.

Comment: @Juice - another small suggestion is to add the interval (per year, per month) as an option for the job poster. In some places (like the US and others), it is customary to post the yearly pay - in others, the pay is posted per month (for salaried positions).

Answer (score 3):

We've updated Canadian and Australian dollars to C$ and A$ respectively to disambiguate from USD. These are the only currencies from the list we allow that share the same symbol.

Comment: I'm glad you've added some hints, but this does not solve my original specific issue.  Here's a new posting which demonstrates it: http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/107673/senior-software-engineer-java-rubyonrails-pocketmath - note that this job is in Singapore, and I'm pretty sure the listed salary is in Singapore Dollars (SGD), but it just says `$`.  I don't understand why you say that CAD and AUD are the "only currencies from the list we allow that share the same symbol".  Assuming it's indeed SGD, how will a USA/AUS/CAN person know?

Comment: The issue still remains. I'm in Australia and looking at jobs posted with $. Is that Australian dollars or US dollars?